# problems with SIGSEGV when working on binary search tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

i'm working on binary search tree ,i expect to put smaller number at the left side of the node,as well as greater at the right side of the node,and output the full traversal.However,i met with SIGSEGV when using pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int key;
};

node* root;
void createnode(int data,node* ptr);
void traversal(node* ptr);

int main(void)
{
srand(time(NULL));
int j;
root = NULL;

for(j=1;j<=16;j++){
    createnode(rand(),root);
}
root=NULL;
traversal(root);

   return 0;
}

void createnode(int data,node* ptr){
    if(ptr==NULL){
        ptr->left=new node;
        ptr->right=new node;
        ptr->key=data;
        ptr->left=NULL;
        ptr->right=NULL;
    }
    else if(data<ptr->key){
        createnode(data,ptr->left);
    }
    else if(data>ptr->key){
        createnode(data,ptr->right);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"error";
    }
}

void traversal(node* ptr){
    if(ptr->left==NULL&&ptr->right==NULL){
        cout<<ptr->key;
    }
    else if(ptr->left!=NULL){
        traversal(ptr->left);
        cout<<ptr->key;
    }
    else if(ptr->right!=NULL){
        traversal(ptr->right);
        cout<<ptr->key;
    }
}
```

Also,i am not sure whether to declare node* left,node* right or not,if yes where should i declare it.thank you.

Comment: `if(ptr==nullptr) { ptr->...;` -- You can't dereference a `nullptr`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i have replaced all nullptr with NULL,what else can i do ,tks

Comment: @930727fre Using `NULL` instead of `nullptr` doesn't change anything.  You cannot dereference a null pointer, no matter what null pointer constant was used to make it null.  Your `root` pointer doesn't point to anything, and so any attempt to use the thing it points to is invalid.

Comment: SEGV gives you a core file and/or stops the debugger right where it happens. Have you tried examining the core file with your debugger, or reproducing the error when running in the debugger? You have lots of information available that you haven't looked at yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate (maybe to yourself) on what you expect this to do:

```
root=nullptr;
traversal(root);
```

Once you get into:

```
void traversal(node* ptr)
{
    if(ptr->left==nullptr // <-- this checks the ->left of nullptr
```

you'll get a crash, because `nullptr` doesn't have a left. What did you expect traversal to do? You probably meant to point `root` to something, before calling the traversal.